# CATransform3d/CGAffineTransform add perspective to existing animated transform?

Tags: ios, animation, matrix, cgaffinetransform, catransform3d

I created an animation via `CGAffineTransform`. I used `animateWithDuration:` and set transform in it. But I forgot that all the views additionally should be translated from a defined point with perspective. I want to achieve the similar perspective transform:

http://cdn.iphonehacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/ios-8-safari-tab-view.jpg

As I think:

- it is 3D space;
- all the rects equally have one edge which belongs one invisible surface;
- all the rects have equal angles (and so all the rects are parallel);
- a human's look is focused on the center so it seems for human that all the rects have different angles (but it happens due to perspective effect only).

As I understand `CGAffineTransform` and `CATransform3D` are convertible between themselves so there is no difference between they for me.

The problems:

1)I know how to represent rotation, scaling, translation and etc. But how to implement a perspective around an anchor point? Which actions and in which sequence should I perform?

2)Even if I'll find the correct action sequence then how to apply them to the existing animated CGAffineTransform? As I understand one half of transforms should be static and another one should be animated. How to merge them?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm encountering something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

I have written code but without perspective.

The reason I declined perspective is it is too slow.

In iPad you can't optimize the app by removing the invisible pages because all of them may be visible (or too near from the edges to release them). So you can reduce their size only. It is strange but if you want to implement the iphone version then you can't optimize the size but can optimize the invisible pages.

In iPad you need too much calculations and so redraw calls too. Additionally you could store `UIWebView` objects in the background which consumes a lot of memory (I checked for many instances of `UIWebView`s with website [onliner.by](http://onliner.by) - it is just "hard" and complex website). And everything becomes slow even before apple generates memory warning.

**Problem 2**

**Warning!** `CGAffineTransform` and `CATransform3D` are convertible between themselves only sometimes. At least not every `CATransform3D` could be converted into `CGAffineTransform` for example if it contains perspective as in my case.

In my case I needed both `CATransform3D` and `CGRect` because even if you apply the first one then you just scale the whole view but if you apply the second one you decrease the bounds of the view but its subviews are not scaled proportionally and some properties (for example font size) are not scaled at all and you need to scale them manually. Finally I used the following combinations:
1)the bounds is fullscreen with center in the screen center;
2)the same as 1 but with applied transform to scale and move to the appropriate position;
3)the same as 2 but I removed the scaling from the `transform` property and added it again via smaller bounds and decreased the sizes, fonts and etc. where it is necessary. This state is just to reduce the memory consumption.